# Arduino Serial Communication C#

Tags: c#, arduino

Everything works, I don't have any error but when I try to disconnect from Port it just freeze and after I just stop the app and reopen it, it doesn't work anymore and I need to upload the code from Arduino again to work. I am sending values from(0-256) 4 potentiometers.
Also I send 100 98 the position of potentionmeter and after the amount together.
so it be like ex 100 98 1 11 110 |
                 100 98 2 21 221 |
                 100 98 3 29 230 |
                 100 98 4 58 260 |
                 and so on again till I disconnect.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace SerialPortConnect
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }


  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
  cmbPort.Items.AddRange(ports);
  cmbPort.SelectedIndex = 0;
  btnDisconnect.Enabled = false;
 }

 private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
 {
        if (serialPort!= null && serialPort.IsOpen)
        {
            serialPort.Close();
        }
 }

  private void BtnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnConnect.Enabled = false;
        btnDisconnect.Enabled = true;
        try
        {
            serialPort.PortName = cmbPort.Text;
            serialPort.DataReceived += DataReceivedEvent;
            serialPort.Open();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

private void BtnDisconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnConnect.Enabled = true;
        btnDisconnect.Enabled = false;
        try
        {
            serialPort.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

 void DataReceivedEvent(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        int suma = 0;
        SerialPort senderPort = (SerialPort)sender;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2];

        if (senderPort.Read(buffer, 0, 2) != 0)
        {
            int val_magica1 = (int)(buffer[0]);
            suma += val_magica1;
            if (val_magica1 == 100)
            {
                if (senderPort.Read(buffer, 0, 2) != 0)
                {
                    int val_magica2 = (int)(buffer[0]);
                    suma += val_magica2;

                    if (val_magica2 == 98)
                        if (senderPort.Read(buffer, 0, 2) != 0)
                        {
                            int poz = (int)(buffer[0]);
                            suma += poz;
                            if (poz == 1)
                                if (senderPort.Read(buffer, 0, 2) != 0)
                                {
                                    int data = (int)(buffer[0]);
                                    suma += data;
                                    if (senderPort.Read(buffer, 0, 2) != 0)
                                    {
                                        int suma_primita = (int)(buffer[0]);
                                        suma=suma%256;
                                        Console.WriteLine("Suma soft1: "+suma);
                                        Console.WriteLine("Suma arduino1: "+suma_primita );
                                        if (suma == suma_primita)
                                        {
                                            SetText1(Convert.ToString(data));

                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            if (poz == 2)
                                if (senderPort.Read(buffer, 0, 2) != 0)
                                {
                                    int data = (int)(buffer[0]);
                                    suma += data;
                                    if (senderPort.Read(buffer, 0, 2) != 0)
                                    {
                                        int suma_primita = (int)(buffer[0]);
                                        suma = suma % 256;
                                        Console.WriteLine("Suma soft2: " + suma);
                                        Console.WriteLine("Suma arduino2: " + suma_primita);
                                        if (suma == suma_primita)
                                            SetText2(Convert.ToString(data));
                                    }
                                }
                            if (poz == 3)
                                if (senderPort.Read(buffer, 0, 2) != 0)
                                {
                                    int data = (int)(buffer[0]);
                                    suma += data;
                                    if (senderPort.Read(buffer, 0, 2) != 0)
                                    {
                                        int suma_primita = (int)(buffer[0]);
                                        suma = suma % 256;
                                        Console.WriteLine("Suma soft3: " + suma);
                                        Console.WriteLine("Suma arduino3: " + suma_primita);
                                        if (suma == suma_primita)
                                            SetText3(Convert.ToString(data));
                                    }
                                }

                            if (poz == 4)
                                if (senderPort.Read(buffer, 0, 2) != 0)
                                {
                                    int data = (int)(buffer[0]);
                                    suma += data;
                                    if (senderPort.Read(buffer, 0, 2) != 0)
                                    {
                                        int suma_primita = (int)(buffer[0]);
                                        suma = suma % 256;
                                        Console.WriteLine("Suma soft4: " + suma);
                                        Console.WriteLine("Suma arduino4: " + suma_primita);
                                        if (suma == suma_primita)
                                            SetText4(Convert.ToString(data));
                                    }
                                }
            }   }       }
        }
    }
private void SetText1(string text)
    {

        if (this.afisare1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            try
            {
                SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText1);
                this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.afisare1.Text = text;
        }
    }
    private void SetText2(string text)
    {

        if (this.afisare2.InvokeRequired)
        {
            try
            {
                SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText2);
                this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.afisare2.Text = text;
        }
    }

    private void SetText3(string text)
    {

        if (this.afisare3.InvokeRequired)
        {
            try
            {
                SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText3);
                this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.afisare3.Text = text;
        }
    }
    private void SetText4(string text)
    {

        if (this.afisare4.InvokeRequired)
        {
            try
            {
                SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText4);
                this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.afisare4.Text = text;
        }
    }

    private void BtnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(send.Text);
        if(serialPort.IsOpen)
        serialPort.Write(data,0,0);
    }
}
```

}
 // Arduino is just sending so I guess is now problem there.

Comment: Find out where the code is stopped.  Use menu Debug : Break All

Comment: How to break all?

Comment: I recently start to use visual studio so im not so familiar with debugging.

Comment: Use the menu bar in Visual Studio.  Start application then use menu : Debug : Break All.  Then see what line of code is highlight

Comment: I don't have break all.Just new breakpoint or Toogle breakpoint.

Comment: You will while you are running.

Comment: So it stop at serialPort.Close(); but have no idea why would stop there.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are even getting there.  Maybe the form is closing?  Make sure the settings for the serial port has handshaking off (both software and hardware).  Once you press Break All you can use Debug : Windows : Call Stack which will give you all the methods called.